# Can we play music continuously without user interaction with the google home devices

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant

Can we play music indefinitely on Google Home Mini or Google? I am working on an action that plays songs. To test it out, I left it overnight to play music. But when I woke up in the morning, the music wasn’t being played by the device. There is a loopback feature that starts playing songs from the start if all the songs have been played.

Is there any such restriction/requirement that needs a user to continuously interact with the device after some duration of time?

I am working on https://github.com/internetarchive/internet-archive-voice-apps

There was no error log but it stopped playing songs after some time even though the album wasn’t finished.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would help if you described exactly how you were "playing songs", since there are several ways to do so. Knowing your exact environment, seeing screen shots of the scenes and/or intents, the code you used, and any errors that were logged would help us to help you better. The more you provide - the better our chances are of helping you figure out the problem. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Added the source. It has the intents and code. No errors were seen.

Comment: I'm not sure about a maximum duration, but can you determine how long audio was playing?